# ruby sort_by twice

Tags: ruby

Ruby has a sort_by method on Enumerables.  Fantastic!  So you can do something like

```
entries.sort_by { |l| l.project.name }
```

That would sort a bunch of entries by their project names.  How could you work it so that within projects that had the same name, entries were sorted by their time?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would suggest putting the column you want to sort by into an array.

```
entries.sort_by { |l| [l.project.name, l.project.time] }
```

This will respect the natural sort order for each type.

Comment: If you want the secondary sort to be most-recent-first, do this: `now = Time.now; entries.sort_by { |e| e.project.name, now - e.project.time }`

Comment: entries.sort_by { |e| e.project.name, -e.project.time }

makes more sense.

Comment: Not bad Antti, not bad at all!

Comment: Specifically, the first element has highest precedence, and the next element decides a tie.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the regular sort method to do it.

```
entries.sort do |a, b|
  comp = a.project.name <=> b.project.name
  comp.zero? ? (a.project.time <=> b.project.time) : comp
end
```

Comment: the nonzero? method can be helpful here:  sort {|a,b| (a.project.name <=> b.project.name).nonzero? or (a.project.time <=> b.project.time)}

Answer (score 3):

Return an array:

```
entries.sort_by { |l| [ l.project.name, l.project.time] }
```

this works because the `<=>` operator on arrays does a field-by-field 'lexical' comparison which is what you're looking for.