# Ruby Array sorting

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array of items that I need to sort. I need to sort by two attributes but currently one sort is overwriting the other. I need a sort of mixed sort so it does one sort inside another.  Any ideas. Here's what I have:

```
    @coasters = @coasters.sort_by { |c| c.coaster_sort }
    @coasters = @coasters.sort_by { |c| c.park_name }
```

Thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   @coasters.sort_by! { |c| [c.coaster_sort,  c.park_name]}
```

Comment: Will accept when it lets me. Thanks!

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov This behaves similar to  SQL  `ORDER BY col1, col2`

Comment: @AntarrByrd ah, now it's clear, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array with the most important sort first:

```
@coasters = @coasters.sort_by {|c| [c.coaster_sort, c.park_name]}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers have already mentioned, you can pass an array:

```
@coasters = @coasters.sort_by {|c| [c.coaster_sort, c.park_name]}
```

This is a repeat of the following question I believe: [ruby sort_by twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442546/ruby-sort-by-twice)