# How can I set a fallback ordering system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, list, sorting

I'm printing a list, ordered as such:

```
<% @users.order(:number).each do |u| %>
  <%= u.name %>
<% end %>
```

But some users will have the same value of `:number`, and in that case the records appear to be ordered based on `time_created`. How can I set a fallback or secondary ordering system to be used when records have the same value of the attribute used to order them?

Comment: Not ready to flag as a duplicate but you may find an answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587776/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-sort-with-two-columns-using-activerecord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just keep adding on to the `order` method.

```
@users.order(:number, :name, :last_logged_in, :id)
```

If the numbers are the same, it will break the tie with name, then last_logged_in, then id. This is all done in the database for you.

If you already had the data in memory, then you could use Ruby's `sort_by` method.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to use `sort_by` instead of `order`.

`@users.sort_by {|u| [u.number, u.second_option] }`

that will sort first by number and then if number matches it will pull whatever the second option is and compare by that. Technically you can throw as many things to sort by as you want into that array.

Edit: Actually, there's a similar question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442546/ruby-sort-by-twice)